# Apple Preview Program messed up the shortcuts after the Yosemite update

Tags: mac, software-update, preview, macos, shortcut

I am trying to annotate my documents with text. In the old preview, I could change to Text Box and click where I wanted to place the text on my document. It would stay on text box and I could click around and conveniently put multiple texts boxes around the page.

After the update to 10.10, when I use the shortcut Control+command+T, it places a text box in the middle of the page(where I don't want it) and keeps selection tool on... I can't put multiple text boxes around the page because it goes right back to highlighting text. I also have the issue with arrows and lines. It places one when I use the shortcut, but I can't use my mouse to guide where it goes.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/151282/67260

Comment: I just installed the upgrade, and I still have this issue. Has this been fixed for anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with Apple support and was informed that it's a bug in the initial release 10.10 build (14A389). It's not yet clear if the 10.10.1 (14B25) update has fixed this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I figured out, that I could copy a version of the old Preview app (verison 7) from a friend who hadn't upgraded, and install it on my computer, and now it works like a charm.